# Remapping isn't working

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

So I code very often but I use an US-international keyboard layout, and what bothers me the most is that I can't type `'` or `"` to open the string because my keyboard layout inputs `´` first then I have to hit space to let the IDE know that I'm using open the string.

So I tried to remap the keys, and in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` I put the dead acute to only be shown when I hit shift, so now my AC11 looks like this:

```
key <AC11> { [  apostrophe, quotedbl, dead_acute,   dead_diaeresis  ] };
```

And then I went to `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` and changed the accented vocals to be set with apostrophe instead of dead acute, so it looked like this before:

```
< dead_acute>< A> : "Á"
```

And I changed to this:

```
< apostrophe>< A> : "Á"
```

- I didn't use the spaces inside the `< >`, but here I had to in other to the text get printed.

So now I thought that everything would work as I wanted, when I pressed " ' " should open the string, and when I pressed `'` and A should output :"Á", but well, it it doesn't open the string now, and when I press `'` + some letter I got no output at all, I mean the cursor erase the `'` and output nothing.

So can you guys help me figuring out how to achieve what I want to do ?

EDIT: 
I figured out how to fix the problem with the '+letters not showing up, but the string still doesn't open, it looks like it waits for me to press '+ something how can I change that behaviour? Because right now I'm at ground zero, changing the `´` to `'` doesn't change nothing in my IDE, to be honest I believe that I should go back to the previous behaviour

Comment: Maybe you simply should try some other keyboard layout. You already know where the `us` symbols file is located. I would suggest that you check out the _English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)_ layout variant.

Comment: I'll try with it and see if I can adapt with the changes

Answer (score 0):

Look at xkeysnail, I believe it can be installed via the repos, but the latest has commits in it that allow for more. I contributed code to allow for <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> functionality.

https://github.com/mooz/xkeysnail